# Plesk point url to an other folder

Tags: hosting, plesk

I have a new hosting with Plesk control panel. My new website is on new hosting but actual url is pointing to previous server.

I created a folder for primary url through Plesk. Of course it complained that DNS servers point to an other location, which is correct. I want to set up project and preview it under a subdomain, so when I update my DNS records website will work. It is a production website.

I created a **new-website.mywebsite.com** and it works. However it creates a new folder **new-website.mywebsite.com**. I can point this subdomain into **mywebsite.com** folder but it when I access my subdomain it comes up with error **403 forbidden**.

Any ideas how I can allow it to work through Plesk? I can ssh into it and edit nginx.config. On the top of the file it says :

```
#ATTENTION!
#
#DO NOT MODIFY THIS FILE BECAUSE IT WAS GENERATED AUTOMATICALLY,
#SO ALL YOUR CHANGES WILL BE LOST THE NEXT TIME THE FILE IS GENERATED.
```

I assume there is a right way to do that through plesk control panel.

Even though if you know what needs to be edited in nginx.conf pease comment below.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe it's better to create in Plesk alias new-website.mywebsite.com for mywebsite.com?

Answer (score 0):

So what I had to do is go to my main website folder `httpdocs` and set permissions as follows

> $ chmod -R 755 httpdocs

That did the trick. Now my subdomain can read from main domain folder.